Is `(input)="true"` idiomatic for Angular OnPush components?
I want to disable button if no files selected.
I have the following template in OnPush component (Angular v19):
@for (item of [1, 2, 3, 4]; track $index) {
  <input (input)="true" #file type="file" />
  <button type="button" [disabled]="!file.files!.length" (click)="onAdd2($index, file.files!)">E{{$index}}</button>
}

I added (input)="true" to trigger change detection, but this doesn't feel idiomatic.
But alternative using signals doesn't work as expected (buttons are not initially disabled) and feel even less idiomatic and requires more code.
@for (item of [1, 2, 3, 4]; track $index) {
  <input (input)="getSignal($index).set(!file.files!.length)" #file type="file" />
  <button type="button" [disabled]="getSignal($index)()" (click)="onAdd2($index, file.files!)">S{{$index}}</button>
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ResultsComponent {
  readonly signals: WritableSignal<boolean>[] = [];

  getSignal(i: number): WritableSignal<boolean> {
    return this.signals[i] ??= signal(false);
  }

  onAdd2(i: number, arg0: FileList) {
    console.log(i, Array.prototype.map.call(arg0, x => x.name));
  }
}

What would you suggest?

This would be a more idiomatic way:

the whole model is stored in the component;
a single WritableSignal<FileList[]> instead of WritableSignal<FileList>[];
a local template variable to help with readability.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  template: `
    @for (_ of [1, 2, 3, 4]; track $index) {
      @let fileList = fileLists()[$index];
      <input #input type="file" (input)="selectFiles($index, input.files!)" />
      <button
        type="button"
        [disabled]="!fileList?.length"
        (click)="uploadFiles($index, fileList!)"
      >E{{$index}}</button>
    }
  `,
  standalone: true,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ResultsComponent {
  readonly fileLists = signal<(FileList | null)[]>([]);

  selectFiles(index: number, fileList: FileList): void {
    // es2023
    this.fileLists.update(fileLists => fileLists.with(index, fileList));

    // before es2023
    // this.fileLists.update(fileLists => {
    //  fileLists[index] = fileList;
    //  return [...fileLists];
    // });
  }

  uploadFiles(index: number, fileList: FileList) {
    console.log(index, Array.prototype.map.call(fileList, x => x.name));
  }
}


Using signals for such a use case is overkill, you can simply declare an instance variable to store the files and remove the template variable :
@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    @for (item of [1, 2, 3, 4]; track $index) {
    <div>
      <input (change)="files[item] = $any($event).target.files" type="file" />
      <button
        type="button"
        [disabled]="!files[item]?.length"
        (click)="onAdd2(item)"
      >
        E{{ $index }}
      </button>
    </div>
    }
  `,
})
export class ResultsComponent {
  files: Record<number, FileList | null> = {};

  onAdd2(item: number) {
    const itemFiles = this.files[item];
    console.log(item, Array.prototype.map.call(itemFiles, (x) => x.name));
  }
}


By the way in Angular 19, Components are standalone by default so you can remove standalone: true.
